# MS Access SQL Sum without GROUP BY

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to add a Sum 'field' to a SELECT query, where it sums up the data on that row, and returns it as a field. The problem seems to lie with the GROUP BY statement, that I seemingly have to use. When using this, it groups the 'sums' together, rather than provides a total for each row of data.

```
SELECT PS_DB.TeamName AS [Team Name], TM_adjData.SM_adjName AS Adjudicator, PS_DB.WeekEnding AS [Week Ending], PS_DB.Pts AS [BAU Points], PS_DB.Adhc, Sum(PS_DB.Pts + PS_DB.Adhc) as [Total], PS_DB.Approved AS Approved
FROM PS_DB
LEFT JOIN TM_adjData on PS_DB.Adjudicator = TM_adjData.SM_empNum
GROUP BY TeamName, SM_adjName, WeekEnding, Pts, Adhc, Approved
```

This returns 518 rows, where as if I remove the GROUP BY section and the 'sum' field, it returns 1,608 rows (which is correct).

How can I get the 1,608 rows with the sum next to it?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform a sum for each row, you don't group rows, instead you simply perform addition. I've added `Nz()` function to properly address issue where any of the value being added is null and treat it as 0:

```
SELECT 
  PS_DB.TeamName AS [Team Name], 
  TM_adjData.SM_adjName AS Adjudicator, 
  PS_DB.WeekEnding AS [Week Ending], 
  PS_DB.Pts AS [BAU Points], 
  PS_DB.Adhc, 
  Nz(PS_DB.Pts,0) + Nz(PS_DB.Adhc,0) as [Total], -- this is your row sum
  PS_DB.Approved AS Approved
FROM PS_DB
LEFT JOIN TM_adjData on PS_DB.Adjudicator = TM_adjData.SM_empNum
```

`SUM` is an aggregate function and it works on entire table or groups of data (with `GROUP BY`).

Comment: That was my original query (nearly) but the COALESCE function isn't recognised in MS Access SQL.

Comment: Thanks though @Kamil - this did infact fix the issue. I realise the SUM() function is what prevented it from working.

Comment: @RazorKillBen changed to `Nz()` function available in MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.TeamName AS [Team Name], a.SM_adjName AS Adjudicator, 
       p.WeekEnding AS [Week Ending], p.Pts AS [BAU Points], p.Adhc,
       (SELECT SUM(p2.Pts + p2.Adhc)
        FROM PS_DB as p2
        WHERE p2.TeamName = p.TeamName  -- perhaps more conditions are needed
       ) as [Total],
       p.Approved AS Approved
FROM PS_DB as p LEFT JOIN
     TM_adjData as a
     ON p.Adjudicator = a.SM_empNum;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon - this results in the correct amount of rows, but an incorrect Sum. Happy to provide sample data and results, but not sure best way to format when editing the post?

Comment: @RazorKillBen . . . Your question does not give enough information to determine what sum you want.  You need to adjust the correlation clause, as the answer specifies.